# How can I modify the Bundle ID of an application already installed on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bundle-identifier

I would like to modify the bundle ID of an application installed on my iPhone so I would be able to install another instance of it. I do not need other ways to get around this, I need to be able to change the bundle ID. I have xcode, and can get other things if I need them and have the patience for it if it is an involved process. Thanks in advance! :)

Edit—I know it is not possible to actually change a specific apps Bundle ID; creating a new copy of the app works perfectly for me. I just needed to have a copy of the application that is exactly the same except for a different Bundle ID. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: If you have the source code then you can compile a new build with a different bundle id. If it is a binary from the App Store then you can't change the bundle id since that would invalidate the app signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out, despite people telling me it wasn't possible :(

I created a new xcode project and set up my developer certificates in the project, then I pretty much followed the instructions on [this](https://dantheman827.github.io/ios-app-signer/) github page. I created a new IPA with the modifications I needed and I signed this new IPA through the same xcode project I modified the original IPA through in iOS App Signer. It allows you to change the bundle ID, as well as the application version and name, which is nice to be able to edit as well. Here is the link to the github where i found this application, it also has an aesthetic tutorial on its front page if this happens to be useful for anyone else.

https://dantheman827.github.io/ios-app-signer/

(I feel like i'm probably not explaining well, things tend to make a lot more sense in my head. Check out the github for clearer instructions or maybe someone who understands what i'm trying to say can help me articulate it better if need be)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the bundle identifier of an app. You can create a second app that looks and behaves exactly the same and has a different bundle identifier, but the bundle identifier is what makes it *that* app. It's the identity of the application.

Answer (score 0):

*You can't change bundle id of app which is already installed* in the iPhone.

**You can create new one from developer portal** and use the same for another instance.

> App bundle id registration should go through apple developer site
>   only.

Comment: Ok, then would there be any way I could spoof it somehow?

Comment: No way you can change bundle id of installed app,

Comment: Ok I actually figured this out it is possible.